# How can I set a wallet to use no-coinbase mode before syncing?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, synchronization

I am trying to configure a wallet to use refresh-type=no-coinbase. I am not entirely sure how to do this without waiting until it is done syncing.

As soon as I open `./monero-wallet-cli`, it asks me to create a wallet and proceeds to sync with the blockchain. This is not especially helpful if a user wants to avoid these outputs before syncing.

I tried running the following:

`./monero-wallet-cli --restore-deterministic-wallet --refresh-type=no-coinbase`

`./monero-wallet-cli --restore-deterministic-wallet --no-coinbase`

Neither of these worked.

How can I configure the wallet software to accept an input to avoid scanning coinbase outputs before the wallet is already done syncing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ^C while it's syncing in the foreground. The background refresh will take over while you are at the prompt.

^C while *not* in foreground syncing quits the wallet.